# How to send data from Iphone to Watchkit in OS2 in SWIFT

Tags: swift, watchkit, xcode7, ios9

I want to send a dictionary from iPhone to Watchkit in watchOS 2.

In watchOS 1 it works fine for me with appgroups but in watchOS 2 I know that we have to use `WCSession` but I don't know how to use it.

Please help me find the solution.

Comment: There are many possible ways to transfer data with `WCSession`. Refer to the documentation link in @BeckyHansmeyer's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/) should help you out.

From that post: First, you'll create and activate a WCSession like so:

```
if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    session.delegate = self
    session.activateSession()
}
```

For transferring a dictionary:

```
let applicationDict = // Create a dict of application data
let transfer = WCSession.defaultSession().transferUserInfo(applicationDict)
```

Then, on the receiving end, you'll need to implement `session:didReceiveUserInfo:` ([Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSessionDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WCSessionDelegate/session:didReceiveUserInfo:)). Note, according to Apple's "[watchOS2 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/UpdatetheAppCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH6-SW1),"

> To begin communication, both your Watch app and your iOS app must have an active WCSession object. Typically, each app creates, configures, and activates a session object at launch time and stores a reference to it in a central location. When you want to send data, you retrieve the session object and call its methods.