# Sending Data between iPhone and iWatch

Tags: objective-c, iphone, watchkit, watchos-2

The code below helps to get the data sent from iWatch to iPhone .But not from iPhone to iWatch if we write the code  `-(void)send:(NSString *)action` and in Appdelegate

```
 (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *))replyHandler in wacth extension
```

In the watch extension controller

```
 -(void)send:(NSString *)action 
  {
    NSDictionary *request = @{@"request":action};
    [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:request
      replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *replyHandler) {
     [self setTextForLabelWithData:[replyHandler valueForKey:@"response"]];
         }
     errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"");
    }];
}
```

in Appdelegate

```
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *))replyHandler
  { 
    NSString *action = message[@"request"];
    NSString *actionPerformed;
    if ([action isEqual:@"foo"]) {
        // do "foo" stuff
        actionPerformed = @"foo done";
    } else if ([action isEqual:@"bar"]) {
        // do "bar" stuff
        actionPerformed = @"bar done";
    }
    replyHandler(@{@"actionPerformed":actionPerformed});
}
```

How can it be done ? Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457811/send-messages-between-ios-and-watchos-with-watchconnectivity-in-watchos2

Comment: Do you want to pass data from watch to iPhone?

Comment: http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178664/how-to-send-data-from-iphone-to-apple-watch-in-os2-in-objective-c

Comment: Reply me If you have any queries?

Comment: @user3182143  yes..the answer in the link works but only for watch OS 2,not OS 1 .is it correct ? or am i going wrong anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to update the key from "response" at this line

```
 [self setTextForLabelWithData:[replyHandler valueForKey:@"response"]];
```

to "actionPerformed" to be like that:

```
 [self setTextForLabelWithData:[replyHandler valueForKey:@"actionPerformed"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Watch Connectivity delegate method request to iPhone to Apple Watch and Apple Watch to iPhone.

For more information see tutorial :  http://www.codingexplorer.com/watch-connectivity-swift-application-context/