# Communicating between Apple Watch and iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, watchos-2

I am making a to-do list application. I also made a watchOS extension for it. Now, the user can add/remove to-dos both on the Apple Watch and the iPhone. I need a way to communicate the to-do list array between the watch and the iPhone. I understand that I would need to use `WCSession`, and send messages to one-another. But I could not find any good tutorials on this.

```
//On the watch
- (void)toDosWereUpdated{
  //Send data to phone
}

//On the phone
- (void)toDosWereUpdated{
  //Send data to watch
}
```

Could someone please provide me with some explanation and/or sample code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check how to use WCSession in this great repository: https://github.com/grachyov/Reminders-on-Apple-Watch

It's an open source Apple Watch app which is actually to-do list too.

Comment: I guess this SO answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178664/how-to-send-data-from-iphone-to-apple-watch-in-os2-in-objective-c

Comment: @Balázs Does it help?